# Choose Sixteen Cookies from Five Varieties

Tags: combinatorics

A cookie shop sells 5 different kinds of cookies. How many different ways are there to choose 16 cookies if...

(a) you have no restrictions?

(b) you pick at least two of each?

(c) you pick at least 4 oatmeal cookies, at least 3 sugar cookies and at most 5 chocolate chip cookies?

This is what I have been trying: For part a) I simply count 5 ways for the first slot, 5 ways for the second... continued to $$ 5^{16} $$
part b... This is throwing me off. I do not understand how to implement the condition. would I reserve two spots such as 
$ {4^2} + 5 ^{14} $?

part c... Is it the same principle as above?

Comment: You overcount in part (a). Suppose you pick a vanilla cookie followed by fifteen chocolate cookies. Is this a different outcome than fifteen chocolate cookies followed by one vanilla cookie?

Comment: @Austin Mohr I understand what you are saying, order does not matter here. I'm just still confused about what method I should use then.

Comment: I believe you want to consider the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of 16 into at most five parts.

Comment: So, the number of compositions of 16 is $2^{15}$
But how would I implement the "at most five parts" portion.

Comment: For a) please see Stars and Bars, Wikipedia, or the dozens on MSE. For b) the same. For c), similar, but the at most part will cause some trouble. (We are probably expected to assume that cookies of the same kind are identical.)

Comment: Alright. For part A, the formula to put n indistinguishable items into k distinguishable bins. Is simply n-1 Choose k-1 where n is 5 and k is 16? This gives me 4Choose15 which doesn't make sense to me. Would I have to do 16*5 to be n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **weak composition** of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts is an ordered $k$-tuple of non-negative integers whose entries sum to $n$. For example, $(5, 4, 2, 0, 5)$ is a weak composition of $16$ into exactly five parts.

We can associate this weak composition with a selection of cookies: we purchased 5 cookes of type A, 4 cookies of type B, 2 cookies of type C, 0 cookies of type D, and 5 cookies of type E. In fact, the number of compositions of 16 into exactly five parts counts *precisely* the number of ways to purchase the cookies. Using the method of [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), one could prove the number of weak compositions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, which is $\binom{20}{4} = 4,845$ in this instance.

For part (b), begin by taking two of each cookie. You have no freedom here. Now, it remains to select 6 more cookies with no restrictions. How many ways can this be accomplished?

Handle part (c) similarly to part (b), but be careful to subtract away the selections that have too many chocolate chip cookies.